# t() function doesn't render HTML

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n, theming

It is the `t()` function and the way I assigned value to a `body` field

```
$my_body_content = t('!frequency new comment(s) sent to <a href="!url">!title</a>', array('!frequency ' => $frequency , '!url ' => $url , '!title ' => $title));
$ewrapper->field_body->set(array(
        'value' => $my_body_content 
) );
```

the `$frequency`, `$title` and `$url` are already set. This is the configuration of the `body` field (it allows `a` tag)

[image]

But it is what I get

[image]

**Why it doesn't render the HTML ?**

---

## UPDATE :

I edited the `body` by UI like this

[image]

and it worked! sounds the problem is because of the *PHP* code

Comment: Are you sure that string is generated from the code you are showing? The strings are quite different.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes I'm sure. There is an `IF` statement that this code is used in both sides of True and False position of `IF`. one of them is `comment(s)` another one is `comment` in the sentence

Comment: @kiamlaluno I tried `$my_body_content = '<a href="go">hi</a>';` and it was the result `<a href="go">hi</a>`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I updated the question

Comment: Then it was that: You are using two strings. By the way, if the strings are using plural and singular, there is a Drupal function for that.

Comment: I wonder why it works when the text is insert by UI but it doesn't when the text is inserted programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it. I should have add the `format` to `field_body` assignment as follow:

```
$ewrapper->field_body->set(array('value' => $my_body_content,'format'=>'full_html'));
```

Answer (score 2):

This code should work for you

```
$link = l($title, $url);
$my_body_content = t('!frequency new comment(s) sent to !link', array('!frequency ' => $frequency , '!link' => $link));
$ewrapper->field_body->set(array(
    'value' => $my_body_content 
) );
```

Comment: No, it was the result: `1new comment sent to !link`

Comment: your code works in `hook_preprocess_html` (for testing I used it in this function) but it doesn't work in node area

Comment: I tried `$my_body_content = '<a href="go">hi</a>';` and it was the result `<a href="go">hi</a>`.

Comment: I updated the question